# Cleaning 'stringr str_replace_all' automatic concatenation when matching multiple times

Tags: regex, r, string, substring, stringr

I used `police_officer <- str_extract_all(txtparts, "ID:.*\n")` to extract all the names of the police officers involved in a 911 call from a text file. 
example:

`2237 DISTURBANCE Report taken

        Call Taker:    Telephone Operators Sharon L Moran
  Location/Address:    [BRO 6949] 61 WILSON ST
                ID:    Patrolman Darvin Anderson
                       Disp-22:43:39                 Arvd-22:48:57  Clrd-23:49:45
                ID:    Patrolman Stephen T Pina
                       Disp-22:43:48                                Clrd-22:46:10
                ID:    Sergeant Michael V Damiano
                       Disp-22:46:33                 Arvd-22:47:14  Clrd-22:55:22`

In some parts when it matches more than one `ID:` I get:  `"c(\"    Patrolman Darvin Anderson\\n\", \"    Patrolman Stephen T Pina\\n\", \"    Sergeant Michael V Damiano\\n\")"`.
Here is what I have tried so far to clean the data:
`police_officer <- str_replace_all(police_officer,"c\\(.","")
 police_officer <- str_replace_all(police_officer,"\\)","")
 police_officer <- str_replace_all(police_officer,"ID:","")
 police_officer <- str_replace_all(police_officer,"\\n\","") # I can't get rid of\\n\.`

this is what I end up with
`"    Patrolman Darvin Anderson\\n\", \"    Patrolman Stephen T Pina\\n\", \"    Sergeant Michael V Damiano\\n\""`

I need help cleaning `\\n\`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex with `str_match_all`:

```
\bID:\s*(\w+(?:\h+\w+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZ4wD4/2)

```
> txt <- "Call Taker:    Telephone Operators Sharon L Moran\n  Location/Address:    [BRO 6949] 61 WILSON ST\n                ID:    Patrolman Darvin Anderson\n                       Disp-22:43:39                 Arvd-22:48:57  Clrd-23:49:45\n                ID:    Patrolman Stephen T Pina\n                       Disp-22:43:48                                Clrd-22:46:10\n                ID:    Sergeant Michael V Damiano\n                       Disp-22:46:33                 Arvd-22:47:14  Clrd-22:55:22"
> str_match_all(txt, "\\bID:\\s*(\\w+(?:\\h+\\w+)*)")
[[1]]
     [,1]                                [,2]                        
[1,] "ID:    Patrolman Darvin Anderson"  "Patrolman Darvin Anderson" 
[2,] "ID:    Patrolman Stephen T Pina"   "Patrolman Stephen T Pina"  
[3,] "ID:    Sergeant Michael V Damiano" "Sergeant Michael V Damiano"
```

The regex matches `ID:` as a whole word, then matches zero or more whitespace (with `\s*`) and then *captures* sequences of alphanumerics characters optionally separated with horizontal whitespace. `str_match_all` helps extract the captured parts, so, you can't use `str_extract_all` with this regex.

**Update:**

```
> time <- str_trim(str_extract(txt, " [[:digit:]]{4}"))
> Call_taker <- str_replace_all(str_extract(txt, "Call Taker:.*\n"),"Call Taker:","" ) %>% str_replace_all("\n","")
> address <- str_extract(txt, "Location/Address:.*\n")
> Police_officer <- str_match_all(txt, "\\bID:\\s*(\\w+(?:\\h+\\w+)*)")
> BPD_log <- cbind(time,Call_taker,address,list(Police_officer[[1]][,2]))
> BPD_log <- as.data.frame(BPD_log)
> colnames(BPD_log) <- c("time", "Call_taker", "address", "Police_officer")
> BPD_log
  time                             Call_taker                                        address
1 6949     Telephone Operators Sharon L Moran Location/Address:    [BRO 6949] 61 WILSON ST\n
                                                                   Police_officer
1 Patrolman Darvin Anderson, Patrolman Stephen T Pina, Sergeant Michael V Damiano
>
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess the real problem is when I bring everything into a data frame with `Call_taker`, `time`, `address`, and `Police_officer` .  
`time <- str_trim(str_extract(txt, "                [[:digit:]]{4}"))    
Call_taker <- str_replace_all(str_extract(txt, "Call Taker:.*\n"),"Call Taker:","" ) %>% str_replace_all("\n","")    
address <- str_extract(txt, "Location/Address:.*\n")
Police_officer <- str_match_all(txt, "\\bID:\\s*(\\w+(?:\\h+\\w+)*)")  
BPD_log <- cbind(time,Call_taker,address,Police_officer)  
BPD_log <- as.data.frame(BPD_log)`   we still get `c(` when we bring Police_officer

Comment: I do not know what your final data frame should look like, but note you just added the whole output from `str_match_all` while you only need the `[,2]` dimension. Try `BPD_log <- cbind(time,Call_taker,address,Police_officer[[1]][,2])`.

Comment: Just saw your update, but I would like the data to be presented under one row, which means all the police officers should be in one cell. if you could do that, that'd be great.

Comment: What about `BPD_log <- cbind(time,Call_taker,address,list(Police_officer[[1]][,2]))`?

Comment: Note that I set the column names with `colnames(BPD_log) <- c("time", "Call_taker", "address", "Police_officer")`. You can adjust as needed. Answer is updated.

Comment: Thank you! Now, do you know how to extract everything after the line `Location/Address: `

Comment: I am not sure what you need. [`(?s)Location\/Address:[^\n]*\R(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/mZ7pS4/1)?

Comment: I have posted the full question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785287/parsing-semi-structured-data. Your last answer is giving me a error `Location\/Address`. it's saying  `> str_match_all(txtparts, " (?s)Location\/Address:[^\n]*\R(.*)")
Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "" (?s)Location\/"`

Comment: That is a regex, not the R code. In R, when declaring a regex. you needn't escape the slash.and backslashes must be doubled.